# Insert array into MySQL database not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert some data from array, but it doesn't work. I tried everything :(

```
        $newuser="INSERT INTO users(access_token,access_token_secret) VALUES 
        ("$_SESSION['oauth_token']", "$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']")";
        $donewuser=mysql_query($newuser);
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Also make sure you have `session_start();` loaded. By the looks of it, your quotes are not correct for your session variables.

Comment: quotes are a mess, find a code linter/validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use double quotes inside your query if you are enclosing it within double quotes, if will break your query. Enclose query in quotes properly. You can append the values like :

```
$newuser="INSERT INTO users(access_token,access_token_secret) VALUES 
        ('".$_SESSION['oauth_token']."', '".$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$token = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
$secret = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];
$newuser="INSERT INTO users(access_token,access_token_secret) VALUES 
('$token', '$secret')";
$donewuser=mysql_query($newuser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question should provide more information like what error(s) do you see etc. However, per your query, try this:

```
<?php
// Error handling
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Start the session in order to get the values in $_SESSION arrays
session_start();

// Other code blocks goes here....

// Your query
$newuser = "INSERT INTO `users` (`access_token`, `access_token_secret`) VALUES (" . 
        "'".$_SESSION['oauth_token']."'", 
        "'".$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']."')"; 

// Execute query or show error from mysql
$donewuser = mysql_query($newuser) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Let us know what you see now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with double quote in your query. Try like this

```
 ('".$_SESSION['oauth_token']."', '".$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']."')
```